# ListView with images extremely slow

Tags: java, android, performance, android-listview, bitmap

I have a `ListView` which displays an `ImageView` to show the user the album art and two `TextView`s for album and artist.

However, when I scroll up and down it is always terribly slow.

```
public class DSongListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    Context mContext;
    List<Song> mObjects;

    public DSongListAdapter(Context context, List<Song> songList ) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_song, songList );
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mObjects = songList;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if( convertView == null ){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_song, parent, false);
            holder.titleLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleLabel);
            holder.artistLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artistLabel);
            holder.cover = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.titleLabel.setText( mObjects.get(position).getTitle() );
        holder.artistLabel.setText( mObjects.get(position).getArtist() );
        Bitmap bm = SongManager.loadBitmap(mContext, mObjects.get(position).getAlbumId() );

        if( bm == null )
            holder.cover.setImageDrawable( mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.untitled) );
        else
            holder.cover.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleLabel;
        TextView artistLabel;
        ImageView cover;
    }



}
```

That's the list adapter I created. The `SongManager.loadBitmap()` method returns either a bitmap or null. If it is null I will use a default bitmap from my resources.

**What can I do to increase the speed?** The amazon music player for example is way faster and smoother than mine! Also I have noticed my app takes 42 MB of Ram. Is that too much?

**Edit:**

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap( Context c, int album_id ){
    Bitmap bm = null;
    try {
        final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri,
                album_id);

        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = c.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

        if (pfd != null) {
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return bm;
}
```

Comment: What is the size/resolution of your images? What does `loadBitmap()` look like? Does it cache images that have already been loaded, or are they reloaded from disk every time?

Comment: When you used Traceview to determine where your problem is, what did you learn? When you enabled `StrictMode` to see if you're doing network or disk I/O on the main application thread, what did you learn?

Comment: @CraigOtis Don't know. These images are inside of the mp3 files on my device. They are always reloaded from disk every time because I don't know how to cache them.

Comment: Is that the entirety of your `loadBitmap()` method? You never seem to be assigning anything to `Bitmap bm`

Comment: @CraigOtis Sorry, copying failed :p I posted the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing IPC, and indirect disk I/O, on every `getView()` call. Had you used Traceview, you would have determined that this is the source of your difficulty.

Please consider using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load those images asynchronously and cache them. There are many other such libraries -- see the "Image Loaders" and "Image Views" categories in [the Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/).

Comment: Thanks!! it works! It even reduced the memory from 42mb to 25mb.

Answer (score 0):

You should never do I/O-Operations on the ui thread. Instead of this, you should load your images aynchronously. Luckyly, there are a tone of good libraries for doing this. Just check out this one, it is simple to use and customize: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader